# node-mandrill sending mail via server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mandrill

this is a newbie question on using node-mandrill properly and most probably on node itself as I am still trying to learn it. But since I have seen many examples to use the api key of mandrill directly from the client side and therefore revealing it, I was wondering how exactly it was working when served but got stuck at this point:

I have an app.js serving a public folder...

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mandrill = require('node-mandrill')(API_KEY); 
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.listen(PORT);

function sendEmail ( _name, _email, _subject, _message) {
    mandrill('/messages/send', {
        message: {
            to: 'EMAIL',
            from: [{email: _email , name: _name}],
            subject: _subject,
            text: _message
        }
    }, function(error, response){
        if (error) console.log( error );
        else console.log(response);
    });
}
```

...where a client script is used to collect info from a contact form and send an email upon clicking a submit button.

form.js

```
var contactForm = document.getElementById( 'contactForm' );
            new stepsForm( contactForm, {
                onSubmit : function( form ) {

                    // send email
                    var _subject = 'Contact Request';
                    var _email = contactForm.elements['q4'].value;
                    var _name = contactForm.elements['q5'].value;
                    var _message = contactForm.elements['q6'].value;

                    sendEmail(_name,_email,_subject,_message);

                }
            } );
```

Could you please tell me what's missing/wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call your back-end function from client. You can use Jquery to make Ajax call like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#contactForm').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var _subject = 'Contact Request';
        var _email = contactForm.elements['q4'].value;
        var _name = contactForm.elements['q5'].value;
        var _message = contactForm.elements['q6'].value;

        $.ajax({
          url: '/sendEmail',
          method: 'post',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({ subject: _subject, email: _email}),
          success: function(res) {

          }
        })

      })

})
```

And in your back-end:

```
// some lines skipped

app.post('/sendEmail', function(req, res) {

     //do your stuff
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I then tried the following but it is now returning a 404 error: `POST http://.../sendEmail 404 (Not Found)`. This is what I added in the back-end: `app.post('/sendEmail',function(res,req){
    mandrill('/messages/send', {
        message: {
            to: 'email@email.com',
            from: [{email: req.email , name: req.name}],
            subject: req.subject,
            text: req.message
        }
    }, function(error, response){
        if (error) console.log( error );
        else console.log(response);
    });
});`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. Can you post your full code

Comment: here the [Gist](https://gist.github.com/compmonks/cd628e38750ddad44ca614976ac56478)

Comment: Your route should be `app.get('/sendEmail', function(req, res) {})` instead of  `app.get('/sendEmail', function(res, req) {})`

Comment: you mean `app.post('/sendEmail', function(res, req) {})`? as you mentioned before?

Comment: Oh sorry I made a mistake

Comment: No problem, thanks for the comments! Still the problem remains. see [Gist](https://gist.github.com/compmonks). I suspect it has to do with my low understanding of routes so far. I added a short directory explanation on the gist.